# integer comparision failure

Tags: android, python

Can anyone help to understand why the following integer comparison fails

```
import subprocess
cmd = "adb -s serialid shell getprop sys.boot"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
outs, errs = proc.communicate()
print outs
if outs ==1:
    print "Condition met.."
else:
    print "Condition fail.."
```

OUTPUT:-

```
Z:\loadbuild>python calculate_attempts.py
1

Condition fail..
```

Comment: How does this have anything to do with android?

Comment: Because `adb -s serialid shell getprop sys.boot` is an android command which outputs `1`,I was hoping they would know

Comment: Ahh, didn't see that, my bad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`outs` is the stuff that the process prints to standard output.  As such, it will be a string, not an int.  Since they are different types, the comparison will always fail.

Perhaps your condition should be something like:

```
if outs.strip() == '1':
    ...
```